# How does application insights know logged in user's id (authenticatedUserId)

Tags: angular, okta, appinsights

I am using the following package in my angular application which is integrated with Okta sign in.

package name: "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web"
package is for azure app insights.

I can see that it logs the telemetry along with User's oktaId value under user_AuthenticatedId. see the screenshot.

We need to change our identity provider from Okta to different SecureAuth.

My question is, how does app insights find the user's Okta Id?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The SDK itself doesn't know or set this value, it provides a helper function to allow your application/runtime to set this value.

So as you have a value in this field, something is setting this value. You may also want to check whether the server that is generating the page (using a server side SDK such as C#) may also be populating this value.

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/AISKU/API.md#setauthenticatedusercontext